# Calculating current in a dc circuit

Tags: dc

[image]

How can we get the current \$I\$ if all resistances and current \$I_g\$ are known?

Is there a special name for circuits like this one? Is this some kind of a bridge?

**Edit:**

[image]

**Edit2:**

[image]

Comment: R3 is parallel to R1 - just redraw it and it becomes a much easier visual problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, apparently it is a bridge configuration, but one of the diagonals is shorted, therefore \$R_3\$ ends up in parallel with \$R_1\$ and \$R_4\$ ends up in parallel with \$R_2\$.

If you redraw the schematic you'll see that \$R_3 \parallel R_1\$ and \$ R_1 \parallel R_4\$ are in series with the current generator, therefore if the resistances and \$I_g\$ are known, it is easy to compute the voltage across each resistor and therefore the current in each.

Knowing the current in each resistor then lets you calculate \$I\$ applying KCL.

Comment: I'm not sure how to redraw the circuit. I'll post it in the edit section, could you please review it? If I redraw it as I did, then \$I=I_g\$, which is not correct. I'm really confused with this example.

Comment: @A6SE That circuit is wrong. Once you put those resistances in parallel, the branch in which I flows just disappears. You have to calculate the voltages across the resistances on the equivalent circuit (watch out for their polarities!), only then you can go back to the original circuit, compute the currents in all four resistors and finally get I by applying KCL (Kirchhoff0's current law).

Comment: When you have time, please review the picture in the Edit2 section. Is the transformation good? I don't quite understand how the voltages across \$R_1||R_3\$ and \$R_2||R_4\$ can help.

Comment: @A6SE now the transformations are correct. The voltages across those parallel groups are the same both in the final transformed circuit AND in the original circuit. You use the former to compute them because it's easier. When you have the voltage values, you can compute the currents *in the original circuit*.

Comment: Now that I get it, it seems so much simpler. Thank you.